# How to enable place holders when using pagination in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, placeholder, android-paging-library

I'm trying to display placeholders while getting data from Firestore. This is what I have tried:

```
class BarsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private PagedList.Config config;
    private BarSourceFactory factory;
    private LiveData<PagedList<Bar>> liveData;

    BarsViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);

        config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(true) //Nothing happens
                .setPageSize("15")
                .build();

        factory = new BarSourceFactory();
        liveData = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(factory, config).build();
    }

    LiveData<PagedList<Bar>> getBarLiveData() {
        return liveData;
    }
}
```

When I add `.setEnablePlaceholders(true)` nothing happens, no placeholders are displayed. Can someone help me display placeholders? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: placeholders are enabled by default (see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList)), that's why nothing happens

Comment: @atarasenko Removing the call to `.setEnablePlaceholders(true)` doesn't change anything. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Before **adding support for placeholders**, though, keep the following **preconditions in mind**:

1. **Requires a countable data set**: Instances of DataSource from the Room persistence library can efficiently count their items. If you're using a custom local storage solution or a network-only data architecture, however, it might be expensive or even **impossible to determine how many items comprise your data set**.
2. **Requires adapter to account for unloaded items**: The adapter or presentation mechanism that you use to **prepare the list for inflation needs to handle null list items**. For example, when binding data to a ViewHolder, you need to provide default values to represent unloaded data.
3. **Requires same-sized item views**: If list item sizes can change based on their content, such as social networking updates, crossfading between items doesn't look good. **We strongly suggest disabling placeholders in this case**.

Comment: Hi Rishabh and thanks for taking the time to answer my question. So you basically say that is impossible to determine how many items are coming from Firestore and that's why I get no placeholder displayed?

Comment: Correct. You must know the size of your data set.
when you don't enable the place holder, scrollbar appears to your list and when you reached to the bottom of your list, data gets fetched and scrollbar shift it's position. But in case of where data size is uncertain, scrollbar can't be set to it's correct position.

Comment: Ok but is there a way to know the size of the data set so I can display those placeholders?